# Npm gulp grunt difference?

Tags: npm, gruntjs, gulp

a bit confused over those 3. Are they the same thing? I guess not since they are all in the same solution. So what do they do exactly and the relations among them? Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are npm, bower, gulp, Yeoman, and grunt good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788748/what-are-npm-bower-gulp-yeoman-and-grunt-good-for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm vs bower vs browserify vs gulp vs grunt vs webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

`npm` refers to **Node Package Manager**. It's a package manager for node modules. You can use it form the command line to install any package registered on npm registry. People use npm to distribute packages. It host packages related to nodejs and front-end frameworks and libraries.

`grunt` and `gulp` are pretty similar. They are both task runners that execute a list of operations and tasks that you define yourself. Both are helpful in the front-end development realm; they can be used to do a lot of things:

- concat, gulify JavaScript files
- concat CSS files
- use preprocessors to compile languages like Jade, Sass, Less, CoffeeScript
- watch files for changes and execute tasks whenever a file change
- optimize images
- a lot more ...