# Automate this browserify command whenever js file is changed

Tags: node.js, webstorm, browserify

Whenever I change `function.js`, I have to manually run the command below to browserify `function.js` into a `bundle.js`

```
$ browserify function.js --standalone function > bundle.js
```

How can this step be automated such that the command is run automatically in the background whenever `function.js` is modified?

I am using node.js v6.9 with Webstorm 2016.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Have a look at the gulp and grunt sections of this answer: [What are npm, bower, gulp, Yeoman, and grunt good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36789515/3993662). Apart from that, you can create a file watcher in webstorm. Simply type watchers in the search all dialog

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browserify command you want to run is;

```
$ browserify function.js --standalone function > bundle.js
```

Taking reference from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md

Here is the full code for what you need. Only slight modification from the reference code is needed for the opts to Browserify.

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./function.js'],
  standalone: 'function',
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts)); 

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
  return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
       // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy with watchify, Just install 
`npm i -D watchify`

then update your 'package.json' file with a command `"watch" : "npx watchify <source>.js -o <output>.js"`

And your are ready to go with just running your npm command `npm run watch`.