# What is the difference between Grunt and Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gruntjs

I have just started learning AngularJS.
I found that Grunt or Gulp can be used to generate server builds in my AngularJS projects.
But what is the difference between Grunt and Gulp?

Comment: The *exact* difference? Diff the codebase to see… Seriously though, they're two different tools to accomplish similar things. There are a *ton* of Javascript libraries all fulfilling roughly the same task, with slight differences…

Comment: You can find the answer in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287542/what-are-the-differences-between-grunt-gulp-js-and-bower-why-when-to-use-the

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Grunt, Gulp.js and Bower? Why & when to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287542/what-are-the-differences-between-grunt-gulp-js-and-bower-why-when-to-use-the)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both of them in several projects. Where I can decode I use gulp, just because I like the syntax more. In reality - other than taste - it doesn't matter at all. You can do everything with both of them.

Don't want to confuse you, but actually there is a third major player in the picture now called webpack, with which you can create really efficient output (if you take a look you'll understand) but I feel that using this affects your project too much, while switching between grunt or gulp -or something with a similar approach- is very easy. I'm still evaluating webpack, but a lot of ppl are using it already.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Gulp VS Grunt](https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/gulp-vs-grunt-why-one-why-the-other-f5d3b398edc4#.h0w3lfmqk) will help you to make your choice:

> There are two main differences between Grunt and Gulp:
>
> - Grunt focuses on configuration, while Gulp focuses on code
> - Grunt was built around a set of built-in, and commonly used tasks, while Gulp came around with the idea of enforcing nothing, but how
>     community-developed micro-tasks should connect to each other

However, this type of questions is **broad** and **opinion based**. No one can provide a full response to your question :)